# Git-Tfs error when running in powershell. "Retrieve LoaderExceptions"

Tags: git, powershell, tfs

I installed git-tfs using chocolatey on a Windows Server 2012 R2. When I try to check if git tfs installed correctly by typing "git tfs --version", I get the following error:

`Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve LoaderExceptions for more information`

I checked the log files that were created and this is what it shows:

```
[Debug] System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
at GitTfs.Program.DoCustomConfiguration(CustomConfigurationExpression initializer)
at GitTfs.Program.Initialize(CustomConfigurationExpression initializer)
at StrucutreMap.Container..ctor(Action`1 action)
at GitTfs.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I'd really like some help here. What am I missing here?

Comment: You said in powershell. Is it working with `cmd`? Because it doesn't seems to be linked to powershell. Which version of `git-tfs? the last one? And of the .net fwk? Perhaps you could try the last from github: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/releases or a previous one? It would be better to report the issues and the results of these investigations here: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues

Comment: @Philippe No it's not working with `cmd` either. And I was using the latest v0.32.0

Comment: what is the version of .net fwk? 4.7.2 is required.

Comment: @Philippe I am running the 4.7.2. I haven't been able to find a lot of information on this but I did find that this may be related to the DLL files not being able to load properly? How can I fix that?

Comment: You have to do some tests to determine if that's a problem with your configuration or from git-tfs (I personally don't have the problem with v0.32). So 1. test v0.32 from https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/releases to see if that's the chocolatey install the problem 2. Test a previous version v0.31 to see if that's a regression. 3. If you have the possibility, try on other computers, especially different from Win Server 2012R2. 4. Do you have an antivirus which could prevent the loading? And again, prefer reporting the issue and tests results here: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues

Comment: @Aithorusa I downloaded the GitTfs-0.32.0.zip from [github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/releases](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/releases). Then, upzipped the package and add the folder to environment variable. After that, it worked well on my Win Server 2012R2. (This is my newly created server, I only installed git and visual studio 2019 additionally) Please also check the [Prerequisites](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs#prerequisites). You can try to install again with this way.

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT I was running this on a VM. I started things from scratch again and now it's working. Reinstalled .NET framework, Visual Studio 2019 and then Git. Thank you.

Comment: @Aithorusa Glad to know it's working now. I summarized your comment and added an answer. You can mark it which will also help others in the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [document](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs#use-git-tfs) of the git-tfs, we need .NET 4.6.2 and the 2012 or 2013 version of Team Explorer installed (or Visual Studio) depending on the version of TFS you want to target.

There are some changes in the latest version([v0.32.0](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/releases/tag/v0.32.0)) of git-tfs:

- Upgrade to .NET Framework 4.7.2 and upgrade NuGet dependencies
- Add support for Visual Studio 2017. To use it set the environment
  variable GIT_TFS_CLIENT to 2017. Multiple versions of VS2017
  installed side by side, either as different editions like VS2017
  Enterprise and Premium or different VS2017 minor versions are not
  offically supported yet. The current implementation will simply use
  the first version found.
- Add support for Visual Studio 2019. To use it set the environment
  variable GIT_TFS_CLIENT to 2019. The same restrictions as for VS2017
  apply, e.g. multiple versions of VS2019 installed side by side,
  either as different editions like VS2019 Enterprise and Premium or
  different VS2019 minor versions are not offically supported yet. The
  current implementation will simply use the first version found.

We can try to reinstall .NET framework, Visual Studio 2019 and Git if we have any issues when installing git-tfs.

Comment: Requirements have a little changed with last version v0.32. Thanks for pointing that it is not up to date ;)